# Finding the derivaitive of a spline function in Java

Tags: java, apache, spline, derivative

I am currently finding the cubic spline of raw data:

```
    double y[] = { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0 };
    double x[] = { 0.0, 1.0, 8.0, 27.0, 64, 125};
    //these arrays are just an example

    UnivariateInterpolator interpolator = new SplineInterpolator();
    UnivariateFunction spline = interpolator.interpolate(y, x);
    double interpolatedY = spline.value(5.0);
```

And I am using interpolatedY variable in another part of my program. I also need to find the derivative of the UnivariateFuction spline such that I can compute y'(x) where x can be any value. I have tried using the method below:

```
  // function to be differentiated
    UnivariateFunction basicF = new UnivariateFunction() {
                                    public double value(double x) {
                                        return spline.value(x);
                                    }
                                };

// create a differentiator using 5 points and 0.01 step
 FiniteDifferencesDifferentiator differentiator =
         new FiniteDifferencesDifferentiator(51, 0.01);

 UnivariateDifferentiableFunction completeF = differentiator.differentiate(basicF);

System.out.println("y'(x=2) = " + completeF.value(new DerivativeStructure(1,1,0,2).getPartialDerivative(1)));
```

But this looks a but long-winded and it doesn't return the right answer. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`interpolator.interpolate(y, x)` returns a [`PolynomialSplineFunction`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/math3/analysis/polynomials/PolynomialSplineFunction.html#derivative()) that extends the following interfaces:

> 1. [DifferentiableUnivariateFunction (deprecated)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/math3/analysis/DifferentiableUnivariateFunction.html)
> 2. [UnivariateDifferentiableFunction](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/math3/analysis/differentiation/UnivariateDifferentiableFunction.html)
> 3. [UnivariateFunction](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math4/analysis/UnivariateFunction.html)

One thing you can do is, instead of using `UnivariateFunction` and [`UnivariateInterpolator`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6/org/apache/commons/math3/analysis/interpolation/UnivariateInterpolator.html), you can use `UnivariateDifferentiableFunction` and [`SplineInterpolator`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.0/org/apache/commons/math3/analysis/interpolation/SplineInterpolator.html) as follows:

```
SplineInterpolator interpolator = new SplineInterpolator();
UnivariateDifferentiableFunction spline = interpolator.interpolate(y, x);
double interpolatedY = spline.value(5.0);

DerivativeStructure ds = spline.value(new DerivativeStructure(1, 1, 0, 2));
System.out.println(ds.getPartialDerivative(1));
```

**Output**

```
// Function to interpolate f(x) = x^3
// First order derivative  f'(x) = 3x^2
// f'(2) = 12.0
Approximation: 12.167464114832537
Theoretical:   12.0
```

**Notes**

Internally, the spline interpolator computes the [`Natural Cubic Spline`](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicSpline.html). The `Natural Cubic Spline` for your `x` and `y` is
[image]
Since you are trying to evaluate the first derivative at `2.0`, the function of interest is:

```
f(x) = 1.1196 x^3 - 0.43062 x^2 + 0.45455 x - 0.14354
```

Taking the first derivative:

```
f'(x) = 3.3588 x^2 - 0.8612 x + 0.4546
```

Now plugging 2 into `f'(x)`

```
f'(2) = 12.1674
```

Which corroborates the results we obtained previously.